# Mostrar dinámicamente varios checkbox y marcarlos en función de una lista

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

Estoy intentando mostrar una lista de checkbox generados de forma dinámica a partir de una lista
en la base de datos, y al mismo tiempo en función de otra lista marcar los que están activos.

Tengo un modelo que uso en el formulario con la siguiente definición (tiene más campos que no muestro):

```
public class AsesoramientoModel {



   private List<Consulta> consultas;
}
```

**consultas** contiene una lista de una serie de consultas para una persona determinada.

Por otra parte tengo otra clase que contiene la lista COMPLETA de posibles consultas

```
@Entity
public class Consulta {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int id;
    @Column(name="descripcion")
    private String descripcion;
}
```

Entonces tendría dos listas:

```
List<Consulta> listacompleta;

asesoramientoModel.consultas
```

La idea es mostrar la lista completa de posibles consultas para que en el formulario,
se puedan marcar o desmarcar **y de entrada muestre las que ya tengo.**

*Mostrar la lista completa no es problema*.

El siguiente código funciona correctamente para mostrar la lista, pero no sé como vincularlo con la lista de mi modelo del formulario.

**Si le añado el th:field="*{consultas}", falla**

```
<div th:each="consulta: ${consultas}"
    class="form-check-inline form-control-sm">
    <label class="form-check-label"> <input type="checkbox" t
            th:value="${consulta.id}" class="form-check-input"> <span
            th:text="${consulta.descripcion}"></span>

                    </label>
</div>
```

Este sería el formulario:

```
<form th:action="@{/}"
            th:object="${asesoramientomodel}" method="post">

        <div th:each="consulta: ${consultas}"
            class="form-check-inline form-control-sm">
            <label class="form-check-label"> <input type="checkbox" t
                 th:value="${consulta.id}" class="form-check-input"> <span
                 th:text="${consulta.descripcion}"></span>
            </label>
        </div>
</form>
```

Alguna sugerencia?
Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes agregarle el atributo `checked` al tag `<input>`. Te recomiendo que agregues un attributo que marque si una consulta en particular está seleccionada. Por ejemplo:

```
@Entity
public class Consulta {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int id;
    @Column(name="descripcion")
    private String descripcion;

    private boolean checked;
}
```

Antes de mostrar el formulario, seteas esta condición:

```
preCheck() {
  Set<Consulta> consultasSeleccionadas = ...;
  listacompleta.forEach(consulta -> onsulta.setChecked(consultasSeleccionadas.contains(consulta)));
  render(listaCompleta);
}
```

Luego en la vista:

```
<input type="checkbox" th:checked="${consulta.checked ? 'checked' : ''}">
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias. Como la seda tu sugerencia. Solo que lo que me comentas para la vista no funcionó. Simplemente lo cambié por:  th:checked="${consulta.checked}"

Comment: @davisoski Ah, perfecto! Gracias por la aclaración. El código lo escribí basado en mi memoria, hace tiempo que no uso JSP.

Recuerda hacer upvote/aceptar la respuesta como correcta :D